# Input not going through for a chat server app

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I am in the process of trying to make a chat app in Java for Android, but first I am trying to make one that runs in Eclipse. The app can connect to the server that I have made but for some reason, it won't get past the name input method. This is my first real project, so I am sorry if it is a really simple mistake! Any help is greatly appreciated.

These are the two relevant methods in the App class:

```
private void run() throws IOException
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 59001);
            in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                //System.out.println(line);
                if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                    out.println(getName());
                } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                    System.out.println("Chatter - " + line);
                } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }

        }
```

and

```
    private String getName() {

        System.out.println("Choose a screen name:");
        String name = in.nextLine();  
        return name;

    }
```

This is the relevant method in the Server class:

```
 public void run() {
            try {
                in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                // Keep requesting a name until we get a unique one.
                while (true) {
                    out.println("SUBMITNAME");
                    name = in.nextLine();
                    if (name == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (names) {
                        if (!name.isEmpty() && !names.contains(name)) {
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                out.println("NAMEACCEPTED " + name);
                for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                    writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has joined");
                }
                writers.add(out);

                // Accept messages from this client and broadcast them.
                while (true) {
                    String input = in.nextLine();
                    if (input.toLowerCase().startsWith("/quit")) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + ": " + input);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {
                if (out != null) {
                    writers.remove(out);
                }
                if (name != null) {
                    System.out.println(name + " is leaving");
                    names.remove(name);
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + name + " has left");
                    }
                }
                try { socket.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this what I see on the console:

```
Welcome to the Chat Client. Enter your message or type 'QUIT' to exit.
Choose a screen name:
sfdkgser



fdsd
asd
QUIT
```

As you can see, nothing happens as I enter new lines.

I expect that afterwards it should say Chatter -, with my message but it doesn't. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same scanner instance to read the name. This causes the scanner to wait until a new line is received from the socket input stream. If you want to read it from the command line, you should use another instance of scanner that reads from `System.in`.

Inside method `getName` add a new variable:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

And then use `sc` to read the name, instead of `in`.